# Why is SELECT a KEYWORD, but for example SET an IDENTIFIER?

Tags: h2

When H2 parses a statement it decides that SELECT is a KEYWORD, but for example SET is an IDENTIFIER (in version 1.4.182). Why is SET not a KEYWORD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET` is actually a keyword in all modern versions of H2:
https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords

In old unsupported versions of H2 (1.*.*) it wasn't considered as a keyword due to historic reasons. H2 1.4.182 was released in 2014, do you really have a good reason to use this version in 2023?

In any case, it is a bad idea to use reserved words from the SQL Standard as unquoted identifiers even when database system allows them to be used in that way, these words may still have a special meaning in some contexts.

Comment: Indeed, ParserUtil.getTokenType()